# Get array of array numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this one:

```
let array = [14, 42, 1, 3]
```

And I would like to get the arrays number mapped to this:

```
[1, 0, 3, 2]
```

Here is the reason:

- `1`: because `14` is the second biggest number
- `0`: because `42` is the biggest number
- `3`: ...

What I have tried so far:

```js
let sort = (array) => {
  let result = []
  let x = array.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b - a)
  for (let elem of x) {
    result.push(array.indexOf(elem))
  }
  console.log(result)
}

// Working
sort([14, 42, 1, 3]) // [1, 0, 3, 2]

// Not working, includes the index "0" two times
sort([14, 42, 14, 3]) // [1, 0, 0, 3]
// Expected: [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Something like [ 1, 0, 2, 3]

Comment: can you explain the logic a little bit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take the indices and sort them by taking the value from the given array.

```js
const sort = array => [...array.keys()].sort((a, b) => array[b] - array[a]);

console.log(sort([14, 42, 1, 3]));
console.log(sort([14, 42, 14, 3]));
```

Comment: this is a cool solution, thanks this will help me in the future with similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's because indexOf stops when it finds it's first result.

You could try to change the value to null once it's located the first time, or compare value to values already in the result and ignore those values.

```js
let sort = (array) => {
  let result = []
  let x = array.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b - a)
  for (let elem of x) {
    result.push(array.indexOf(elem))
    array[array.indexOf(elem)] = null;
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sort = (arr) => {
    let arr2 = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a);
    return arr.map((val) => {
        return arr2.indexOf(val);
    })
}
console.log(sort([14, 42, 1, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tracker object, map value and indexes as `key/value` pair and when looping though the `array` take the first index from respective key and shift it as well

```js
let sort = (array) => {
  let result = []
  let x = array.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b - a)
  let tracker = x.reduce((op,inp,i)=>{
    op[inp] = op[inp] || []
    op[inp].push(i)
    return op
  },{})
  
  for (let elem of array) {
    let val = tracker[elem][0]
    tracker[elem].shift()
    result.push(val)
  }
  console.log(result)
}

sort([14, 42, 1, 3]) // working

sort([14, 42, 14, 3]) // includes the index "0" two times
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
(() => {

  function getBiggestOrder (nums) {
    const lookup = {}
    const result = nums.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b - a).map((num, i) => {
      lookup[num] = i
      return num
    })
    
    return nums.map(n => lookup[n])
  }

  const op = getBiggestOrder([14, 42, 1, 3])

  console.log(op)

  return op

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically numbering the numbers from biggest to smallest. sort them in a duplicate array from biggest to smallest. And replace the original array numbers with their index in the duplicate array.

```
Original = [14, 42, 1, 3]
Duplicate = [42, 14, 3, 1]
Duplicate indexes are [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

so find 42 in the first array and replace it with the index of the 42 in the duplicate array, etc.